# Excel: get hyperlink from a linked url

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry for the impenetrable question title. I have a workbook with a load of links in a table, generated by the `HYPERLINK` function as follows:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("http://google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&q=",[@[Patent No]],"&sourceid=navclient"),"Search")
```

The resulting URL searches Google for a patent number `[@[Patent No]]`, and employs Google's "*I'm Feeling Lucky*" to navigate to the first matching page. However many of the patents I get sent to are the wrong language, for example http://www.google.ch/patents/US20150086824. The solution is simple, change .ch to .com in the url.

My question is how to automate this in excel? So get the link of the page where I'm Feeling Lucky will send me, then change .ch to .com, then provide *that* fixed link as the one I get in Excel.

I hope that makes sense, if this can be done with functions then that's best, or vba if necessary. I've had a quick look but found it tricky to word my question when searching.

### Update

Perhaps I should make the I'm Feeling Lucky part a bit more clear. Say I want to search for 'Stack Overflow' on google and click on the first link that Google search comes up with (which more than likely will be https://stackoverflow.com/, but I don't want to just link to the site itself, I want to link to the I'm Feeling Lucky result).
Currently Excel constructs the link like this:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("http://google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&q=","Stack Overflow","&sourceid=navclient"),"Search")
```

Giving the url: [Search](http://google.com/search?btnI=I%27m%20Feeling%20Lucky&q=Stack%20Overflow&sourceid=navclient) inside Excel *with address http://google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&q=Stack%Overflow&sourceid=navclient*

If I click on [Search](http://google.com/search?btnI=I%27m%20Feeling%20Lucky&q=Stack%20Overflow&sourceid=navclient) it will take me to https://stackoverflow.com/ but Excel doesn't know that, nobody knows that until I've clicked on the link **then** *Google decides where the destination is*. Essentially I take a variable search term (Stack Overflow, or a patent number) in Excel, *export* that information to Google (in the form of an *I'm Feeling Lucky* link) to make a decision on where to link to, and then *import* the destination that Google decides on *back into Excel* - where I can substitute the .ch and create a new Search link in Excel.

Comment: would wrapping this up with a replace =replace(whatyouhave,".ch",".com")?

Comment: That would not work, as 'whatyouhave' is the _I'm Feeling Lucky_ link, like this: `http://google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&q=`_`patentnumber`_`&sourceid=navclient` which then takes me to the patent page, but does not itself contain the .ch. It is only once Google has carried out the search that the patent url is decided, but by then the link has left Excel and is now in google so I cannot access it.

Comment: You could try the new Google patent search:  `=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("https://patents.google.com/patent/",[@[Patent No]],"/en"),"Search")`

Comment: @Comintern That would work, except that not all patent references are identical. A number of the google patent references have an added 0 part way through (but not all of them). This isn't a problem for Google search as it gives a best guess, but the patent search returns an error if the patent you're searching for doesn't exactly match one in the Google database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

The important code I have wrapped in a UDF and it returns the first link Google comes up with (same effect as I'm Feeling Lucky but without specifically using that)

```
Function GOOGLE(SearchTerm)
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object
    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String


        url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & SearchTerm & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

            Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("H3")(0)

       'friendlyName = objH3.InnerText
        GOOGLE = objH3.parentElement.href

End Function
```

After that I just need some simple nested functions to switch the country code (which I decided to wrap in another UDF):

```
Function CHANGE_CODE(link As String, newcode As String) As String
    Dim linkst As Double
    Dim trimmed As String
    Dim oldcode As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    linkst = WorksheetFunction.Search("google.", link) + 6
    trimmed = Right(link, Len(link) - linkst)
    oldcode = Mid(link, linkst, WorksheetFunction.Search("/", trimmed))
    CHANGE_CODE = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(link, oldcode, newcode, 1)
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    CHANGE_CODE = link

End Function
```

So that my final spreadsheet code is something like `=HYPERLINK(CHANGE_CODE(GOOGLE(`*`"blah"`*`),".com"),"Search")`

---

I only later realised that `GOOGLE()` is volatile, so to avoid waiting for 100 searches every time I update my sheet, I implement the functions with a macro instead of typing into cells (for "Table 1" with Column A containing search terms, Column B called "Google" containing the results):

```
Sub CallGoogle() 'places a google link in each cell of a table
Dim c As Range
Set Table = Range("Table1[Google]")
For Each c In Table.Cells
    link = CHANGE_CODE(GOOGLE(c.Offset(0, -1)), ".com")
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
        Anchor:=c, _
        Address:=link, _
        ScreenTip:="Google top rank for " & c.Offset(0, -1), _
        TextToDisplay:="Search"
    Next
End Sub
```

Which makes me think putting everything in UDFs was kinda stupid, but they can be easily fixed if you want to!